# c++ linux system command

Tags: c++, c, linux, function, system

I have the following problem:

I use in my program this function:

```
  system("echo -n 60  > /file.txt");
```

it works fine.

But I don't want to have constant value. I do so:

```
   curr_val=60;
   char curr_val_str[4];
   sprintf(curr_val_str,"%d",curr_val);
   system("echo -n  curr_val_str > /file.txt");
```

I check  my string:

```
   printf("\n%s\n",curr_val_str);
```

Yes,it is right.
but `system` in this case doesn't work and doesn't return -1. I just print string!

How can I transfer variable like integer that will be printed in file like integer, but don't string?

So I want to have variable  int a  and I want to print value of a with system function in file. A real path to my file.txt is /proc/acpi/video/NVID/LCD/brightness. I can't write with fprintf. I don't know why.

Comment: You are going to find many problems trying to write multi-language source files. I suggest you stick to only 1 of C or C++.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you cannot concatenate strings like you are trying to do. Try this:

```
curr_val=60;
char command[256];
snprintf(command, 256, "echo -n %d > /file.txt", curr_val);
system(command);
```

Comment: This is worth +1 just for using `snprintf` instead of `sprintf`.

Answer (score 8):

The `system` function takes a string.  In your case it's using the text *curr_val_str* rather than the contents of that variable.  Rather than using `sprintf` to just generate the number, use it to generate the entire system command that you require, i.e.

```
sprintf(command, "echo -n %d > /file.txt", curr_val);
```

first ensuring that command is large enough.

Answer (score 7):

The command that is actually (erroneously) executed in your case is:

```
 "echo -n curr_val_str  > /file.txt"
```

Instead, you should do:

```
char full_command[256];
sprintf(full_command,"echo -n  %d  > /file.txt",curr_val);
system(full_command);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
#define MAX_CALL_SIZE 256
char system_call[MAX_CALL_SIZE];
snprintf( system_call, MAX_CALL_SIZE, "echo -n %d > /file.txt", curr_val );
system( system_call );
```

[man snprintf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf)

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using C++'s iostreams facility instead of shelling out to `echo`? For example (not compiled):

```
std::ostream str("/file.txt");
str << curr_val << std::flush;
```

Alternately, the command you pass to `system` must be fully formatted. Something like this:

```
curr_val=60;
std::ostringstream curr_val_str;
curr_val_str << "echo -n " << curr_val << " /file.txt";
system(curr_val_str.str().c_str());
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct way would be similar to this:

```
curr_val=60;
char curr_val_str[256];
sprintf(curr_val_str,"echo -n  %d> /file.txt",curr_val);
system(curr_val_str);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just DON'T. :)

Why resort to `system()` for such a simple operation?

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

int write_n(int n, char * fname) {

    char n_str[16];
    sprintf(n_str, "%d", n);

    int fd;
    fd = open(fname, O_RDWR | O_CREAT);

    if (-1 == fd)
        return -1; //perror(), etc etc

    write(fd, n_str, strlen(n_str)); // pls check return value and do err checking
    close(fd);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `snprintf` to avoid security issues.

Answer (score 0):

What about using `std::string` & `std::to_string`...

```
std::string cmd("echo -n " + std::to_string(curr_val) + " > /file.txt");
std::system(cmd.data());
```